# Can not install Ubuntu after manually deleting partition

Tags: 12.04, 14.04

Since I had some problems with my Ubuntu 12.04.1 In a dual boot system with Windows 7 on Acer 5560G, I had to manually delete the partition containing Ubuntu. Then I used windows recovery CD to rescue my grub to log into windows.

Since then, I am unable to install Ubuntu 12.04.5 or 14.04.1, as the installation is stuck in the logo screen in the starting. However, 12.04.1 installation starts, but ends up in error saying couldn't install the grub, and grub rescue appears.

Is the issue due to overwriting MBR or is it due to UEFI or any graphics related issues?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem.

For all users with Acer Aspire 5560G, hope this helps.

Press <kbd>F2</kbd> when system starts to go to Settings. Change the graphics from "switchable" to "integrated".

Since this particular laptop has dual graphics, ubuntu installer was unable to use the graphics with "switchable" mode. Now it should work.